# ARKit face tracking PBR

Tags: cocoa-touch, scenekit, arkit, metal, pbr

I am usig the ARKit face tracking configuration and displaying the face mesh in realtime, i can successfully add diffuse and normal maps to it, and they display correctly, but no luck with roughness or metalness, roughness has no effect and metalness is rendering all black and dull/opaque, things i have tried:

- `self.contentNode?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.roughness.contents = UIColor.black //UIColor.white`
- `self.contentNode?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.metalness.contents = UIColor.black //UIColor.white`
- `self.contentNode?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.roughness.contents = myMetallnessTextureImage`
- `self.contentNode?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.metalness.contents = myRoughnessTextureImage`

It is worth noting that most of the light management is done by the session, thats why the mesh responds to the ambient and direct light when using it, and when there is only ambient light, the mesh looks di-electric/rough, and when there is a strong directional light it looks metallic/smooth, is it the session taking control of these params?

If i export the face mesh as an `.obj`, when opening it on Xcode i can tweak the material properties, and i can get a fully metallic shiny face, but when applying the same params to my mesh in realtime they do not work.

In the end, what i want is to be able to have some part of the face metallic by using a grayscale map.

Also i am aware that the face tracking config does not allow an environment map(correct me if wrong) so a fully mirror like texture will look quite un-realistic but anyway, it should work.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you manage the scene's lighting environment? Are you using `ARSCNView`? Is your material correctly set to use the PBR lighting model?

Comment: @mnuages Yes, i am using an `ARSCNView` and the material is set too: `material.lightingModel = .physicallyBased`, the scene lightning is handled by the session, `ARFaceTrackingConfiguration` handles the light over the face mesh automatically.

Comment: Do you have any lights in your scene?

Comment: @Hermes not added by me, not sure if this config adds lights, anyway, i solved it, i was missing a param, please check the answer. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Solved, i was missing this parameter in my setup method:

```
sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
```

This adds what seems to be an ambient light to the mesh reflections, and roughness and metalness are taking effect.

Comment: Such an important line of code :)
Thank you much!!!